# Error occurs during executing the examples of selenium with Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

on my system I had Python 2.6 and Robot framework. I have installed Selenium2Library by following the directions according to the link below:
https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library
 but when I try to run the example, its giving me the following error and no firefox window opened.

```
ERROR:  clean-python26-env]$ python testExeJS.py 
======================================================================
ERROR: test_exe_javascript (__main__.ExecuteJavascriptTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testExeJS.py", line 7, in setUp
    selenium.setTimeout("60000")
NameError: global name 'selenium' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Any help is really apreciated

## Edit

I am Sorry I just saw your reply. may be this will help you more to  understand my problem.
The example code link is:
`http://www.wallix.org/2011/07/26/how-to-use-robotframework-with-the-selenium-library/

and my running errors are:

```
$ pybot myFirstTest.txt 

==============================================================================
myFirstTest :: This is your first test                                        
==============================================================================
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open
Go To Google Page [Documentation] Go to google page and search som... | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified\n'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open
Open Selenium Page [Documentation] TestCase for open Selenium page    | FAIL |
No browser is open
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
myFirstTest :: This is your first test                                | FAIL |
2 critical tests, 0 passed, 2 failed
2 tests total, 0 passed, 2 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /data/home/sadikhan/ironport/Selenium/output.xml
Log:     /data/home/sadikhan/ironport/Selenium/log.html
Report:  /data/home/sadikhan/ironport/Selenium/report.html
```

Comment: Can you please link to the source of the example you ate struggling with? Looking at the page I can only see [https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/blob/master/demo/rundemo.py](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/blob/master/demo/rundemo.py)

Comment: Sorry I just saw your comment. May be this will help you more to understand my problem:

Comment: Please see the below answer, and leave comment if it does not solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

ok so here I'm going to annotate the log so that hopefully you can see how to read it and debug from it in the future. I apologise for any inaccuracies, as I'#m used to Selenium2Library:

```
$ pybot myFirstTest.txt 
==============================================================================
myFirstTest :: This is your first test                                        
==============================================================================
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open
```

Ok so here's your first clue - selenium is trying to take a screenshot but doesn't see a browser open - you you see a browser open? Does it open to the correct page?

```
Go To Google Page [Documentation] Go to google page and search som... | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified\n'
```

So here's the next clue - `The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified` - so this points to the problem being that you're running headless, and SeleniumLibrary expects to find a display (please correct me if I'm wrong) so you may need to create one, which is rather easier than it might sound - you will want to install [PyVirtualDisplay](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay) and then from robotframework - try using `| Library | pyvirtualdisplay.smartdisplay.SmartDisplay |` before using SeleniumLibrary.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open
```

And here's the first clue again.

```
Open Selenium Page [Documentation] TestCase for open Selenium page    | FAIL |
No browser is open
```

And this is because of the earlier problems.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
myFirstTest :: This is your first test                                | FAIL |
2 critical tests, 0 passed, 2 failed
2 tests total, 0 passed, 2 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /data/home/sadikhan/ironport/Selenium/output.xml
Log:     /data/home/sadikhan/ironport/Selenium/log.html
Report:  /data/home/sadikhan/ironport/Selenium/report.html
```

Comment: Cool, if this was helpful fell free to edit it to add any information and accept the answer so others with the same problem can see that it helped, otherwise it can be helpful to answer your own question and accept that.